# Record locked in Archer GRC

Tags: record-locking, archer, rsa-archer-grc

When I try to edit a record within Archer GRC, it says another user has it open, but the user has told me they no longer have the record open in their session. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the other user log out of Archer. This is happening because the user still has an open session with Archer GRC. Alternatively an administrator can force the user off the system via the access control, but the former is recommended in case the other user is in the middle of doing some work so that they can finish.

Answer (score 1):

User doesn't have to log out from Archer. User need to open same record, click Edit and click View.
This will release the edit lock you have on the record.

If user is no longer available, but his session is active, he can be logged off by the System Administrator (or any other user with user management role).

Comment: thanks... but, try to explain how the SysAdmin can log them off in detail... like @rohith0904 did.

Comment: @Igritte sorry about this, next time I will make sure to provide screen shots highlighting the buttons to click.

Comment: :-) no need to apologize... it will just be a better answer and lead to you geting more upvotes;-)

Answer (score 1):

  1.Go to Administartion>Access control>Manage Users

  2.Filter for the user responsible for the record lock

  3.Under Actions, you can see him/her as Logged In. Just click on the Logged In which expires his/her session.

  4.Now you can access the locked record.